# Java - How can I print out a value as a word after BubbleSorting?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, int, bubble-sort

I used integer so that I can write out Numbers as an input, but now i would like the programm to output the number as Words again.

```
public class KartenSort {

private int zwei = 2;
private int drei = 3;
private int vier = 4;
private int fuenf = 5;

public int[] liste ={drei,zwei,fuenf,vier};
public int[] sortieren(){

    int unsortiert;
    for(int sortiert = 0; sortiert < liste.length -1; sortiert++){

        if(liste[sortiert] < liste[sortiert+1]){
            continue;
        }

    unsortiert = liste[sortiert];
        liste[sortiert] = liste[sortiert+1];
        liste[sortiert+1] = unsortiert;
        sortieren();
    }
return  liste;
}

public static void  main (String[] args){
    KartenSort bs = new KartenSort();
    int[] array = bs.sortieren();
    for (int sortiert=0;sortiert < array.length; sortiert++){
        System.out.println(sortiert + 1 +":" + array[sortiert]);
    }

}

}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you say *numbers as words*?

Comment: instead of typing "2", writing "two" or what i did in german "zwei"

Comment: "*but now i would like the programm to output the number as Words again*" - You never used "words" (whatever this is supposed to mean), you used variables. If you want to print them as `String`s, you need to convert them, e.g. by some `if`-`else`s or a `switch`. I assume that this is some sort of homework assignment? You should go and speak to your supervisor s/he can explain it way better in person than we can online.

Comment: no, just trying to learn how to code :D but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you could use Map

```
Map<Integer,String> numbers = new HashMap<>();
numbers.put(2, "zwei");
numbers.put(3, "drei");
numbers.put(4, "vier");
numbers.put(5, "funf");

for (int sortiert=0;sortiert < array.length; sortiert++){
     System.out.println(numbers.get(array[sorted]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array `liste` does not contain Strings (what you probably mean by "words").
I think, you wanted to have something like

```
String[] liste = ...
```

Your version of `liste` is

```
int[] liste = ...
```

This means it contains integer numbers, not strings. Although you write

```
int[] liste = {drei,zwei, ...}
```

the content of the array are still integer numbers. `drei` is a variable and you will get the value of the variable into the list. The value of `drei` is the integer value 1.

When you have the value 1 there is no reference back to the name of the variable that had hold it some time ago.

Comment: would there be a way for me to keep the integer in the begining  and convert it before printing it out?

Comment: there are many ways. One simple way is to use a second array like ```String[] woerter = {"null", "eins", "zwei", ...};```. So with ```woerter[sortiert]``` you can get the String for the number.